# Can IIS modify the URI when a call is made to a specific folder?

Tags: image, iis, mod-rewrite, redirect, uri

I have a .NET application that contains over 500 images within a folder /images/. In my presentation layer I am referencing these images using relative paths.

```
<img src="/images/testimage.png" />
```

I'd now like to move these images to be served from an Azure blob storage container. So my new paths would need to explicitly define the full URI of the resource.

```
<img src="https://myarea.blob.core.windows.net/images/testimage.png" />
```

I was about to do a site-wide find replace when it occurred to me that I may be able to reroute these requests using IIS. So my question is can IIS intercept the request to the /images folder and prefix the new URI before serving the file? If so what type of latency would this introduce to the application, other than the time taken to fetch the image from the new location? Most of my image files are .png, .gif and .jpeg, typically 5-20kb and are used for templating, buttons and general formatting.

Comment: What IIS version are you running on?

Comment: We're running on IIS 7.5 but plan to deploy to Azure, which appears to also be based on 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) you could do this.

Match /images/* and redirect to https://myarea.blob.core.windows.net/images/...

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="images to azure" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/images/(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://myarea.blob.core.windows.net/images/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I may fall back on this option but I'm going to try to look for a solution that doesn't rely on installing any 3rd party extensions. I'm planning to run my App in Azure so it would be preferable to use something native to .NET. I'm currently looking at using something like IRouteHandler.

Comment: @QF_Developer Since you are using IIS 7.5, the rewrite module is already part of your installation (it is not a 3rd party extension). I do believe that this is the easiest way to do what you want!

Comment: I tried the above sample but it didn't work and the web.config complains that "rewrite" is an invalid child element. Will this work while debugging in VS? I'm launching from the Visual Studio development server.

Comment: OK I see the rewrite will work only in IIS. I'll try to debug in IIS Express.

Comment: The rewrite is now working but I'm ending up with the following. https://myarea.blob.core.windows.net/images//testimage.png I'm trying to adjust the regex to eliminate the duplicate forward slash.

Comment: @QF_Developer IIS Rewrite is available on Azure (I've used it myself).  If the extra / is always present you could just ditch it from the <action /> element so it's just "...images{R:1}" ?

Comment: Thanks Brendan, that worked!! Although I had to hit F5 a few times to clear the cache. Yes I decided to partition all my images out of the package to speed up deployment to Azure and offload some work to the blob store. Being able to modify the image uri in the web.config is really useful, especially if MS forget to renew their SSL cert.

Comment: Ha, yes I did get stung by that also.  It was a simple fix for me as all I do is host images that don't need to be secured so I could easily switch to non-HTTPS Azure requests.  Others I imagine weren't so lucky!

Comment: I got this working but instead of <match url="/images/(.*)" /> I used <match url="images/(.*)" /> (without the / before images).